# In LYX, how can I eliminate or change page numbering in my Appendix Chapter*?

Tags: lyx, page-numbering

I have tried everything suggested on the web but nothing has worked - yet!

I am writing a thesis with 6 numbered Chapters. 
For page numbering I am using

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

and

```
\pagestyle{headings}
```

starting at Chapter 1, which comes out like this:
[image: First Chapter page numbering working example]

After my six Chapters I add my 'Bibliography', and after that 'Appendices' as an unnumbered *Chapter. However, the page numbers showing in my Appendices have kept in 'memory' the Bibliography (previous) chapter. See here:

[image: PDF view of Appendices section]

I would like to change this so that it shows 'Appendices....page number' or just 'page number' or as a last resort by  eliminating page numbering in the Appendices *Chapter altogether.

Thank you in advance!

Ella

Comment: How did you add appendix in your lyx document? Did you add it as a separate chapter or via document-->start appendix here?

Comment: I added it as a separate Chapter and indluded it in the main document.

Comment: I believe that you should choose the second method. LyX has an "automatic" way to set appendices, which can be seen as a separate document class. But you can try to enter the following commands before your "chapter with appendix": '\cleardoublepage' (if you use a book document class)and then '\pagenumbering{roman or arabic}', '\setcounter{page}{the number you want your appendix to start}'

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the case myself.
The solution is to change the \pagestyle to {plain} at the section I only want numbers showing. My code which now does this is shown below simplified:

```
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic} \pagestyle{headings}
```

Include Chapter 1

...

Include Chapter 6

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 

\pagestyle{plain}
```

Include Appendices

```
\end{document}
```

Thanks you anyhow!